# Would this be correct for kinetic energy in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, mass-energy

In galilean relativity $$p=mv$$ and $$KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

If I understand it in special relativity the equation for momentum is $$p=\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$  In galilean relativity there is the equation $$\frac{p}{m}=v$$ while in special relativity the equation is $$\frac{p}{m}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ In galilean relativity $$KE=\frac{1}{2}m\frac{{p}^2}{{m}^2}$$ and if this equation holds in special relativity it produces the equation $$KE=\frac{1}{2}m\frac{v^2}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$  Is this a correct way to express kinetic energy in special relativity?

Comment: No, because like all the previous equations, $E=p^2/2m$ is not true in special relativity.

Comment: The correct relationship between energy and momentum is $p = Ev/c^2$. You then have to subtract off $mc^2$ and Taylor expand to get kinetic energy.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589970/123208

Answer (score 4):

It is useful to understand how the expression for kinetic energy is arrived at in non relativistic mechanics and apply that for the relativistic case. Let's say we have a body at stand still and apply a force $F = \frac{d(mv)}{dt}$ to get it moving. The energy gained by the body is then

$
E_k = \int_0^t Fdx = \int_0^t \frac{d(mv)}{dt} dx = \int_0^tmv dv = \frac{1}{2} m v^2
$

Doing the same in relativistic mechanics you need to take into account the body gets heavier (or more "inertial") by a factor $\gamma = (1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})^{-1/2}$ with $m$ now its rest mass and the integral works out differently. Calculating the work done we will find:

$
E_k =  \int_0^t Fdx =\int_0^t \frac{d(\gamma mv)}{dt} dx = \int_0^tv d(m\gamma v)
$

This integral is slightly more involved but will result in $E_k = (\gamma -1 ) mc^2$. Physically a lot more work has to be done to accelerate the body as it gets heavier.

Note that in the classical case you can write $E_k = \int_0^t \frac{p}{m} dp = \frac{p^2}{2m}$ but not anymore in relativistic mechanics as you can see from the integral expression in the above which becomes

$\int_0^tv d(m\gamma v) = \int_0^t\frac{p}{\gamma m} dp$.

So your expression for $E_k$ in terms of momentum is incorrect.

Comment: Thank's!  I was also wondering what would be the equation for kinetic energy if $\gamma = (1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})^{-1/2}$ was replaced with $\gamma = \frac{v^2}{c^2}+1$?

Comment: I found $E_k = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 (1 + \frac{3v^2}{4c^2})$ in that case but why are you interested in that? Did you mean $\gamma = 1 + \frac{v^2}{2c^2}$?  That would be the correct $\gamma$ expanded to first order in $\frac{v^2}{c^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Kinetic energy in Special Relativity is $KE=(\gamma -1)mc^2$, where $\gamma $ is the Lorentz factor.  This is derived from the relativistic equation for total energy, $E^2 = (pc)^2 + ((mc)^2)^2$; the negative term removes the rest energy from the total energy.

The Galilean kinetic energy is the limit of this expression for small velocities.

Comment: This should be a comment, an answer should explain why that is correct and why OP's expression is not.

Answer (score 0):

The equation for KE does NOT come from integrating force through some distance/time/velocity. You don't even need calculus.
Of course that does give you the correct equation, it's more just a fun quick way to get the equation.

It's all from the **true** energy-mass equivalence. This works regardless of the speed you have. The approximation of it, is the standard KE used for non-relativistic stuff (as expected, since newtonian mechanics is an approximation)

Namely, 
$E^{2} = (mc^{2})^{2} + (pc)^{2}$

That is the energy-mass equivalence, notice that if momentum is zero, you get the famous $E=mc^2$ (rest energy)

Then to get KE, you just need to subtract resting energy. 
So,

$KE = \sqrt{(mc^{2})^{2} + (pc)^{2}} - mc^2 = mc^2(\sqrt{1+(\frac{p}{mc})^2}-1)$

Like that. If you taylor expand that square root to approximate it, you get $KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. And if you sub in $p=\gamma mv$ for speeds close to c, you'll get $KE=(\gamma -1)mc^2$ after some simplification.