# Why is the kinetic energy for non-relativistic velocities not described by $KE=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics

Today, I learned that the kinetic energy of an object can be described by
$$KE=\gamma mc^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}mc^2.$$

I have been taught in school that the kinetic energy of an object is $$KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$ for non-relativistic velocities.

If we take the first, more precise equation and insert a non-relativistic velocity $v \ll c$, one gets $\frac{v^2}{c^2} \approx 0$, so $$KE=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}mc^2 \approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0}}mc^2\approx mc^2 \neq \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$ (especially since $v \ll c$).

What am I missing here? Is it even possible to derive the non-relativistic kinetic energy formula from the relativistic one?

Comment: Either you were taught something that isn’t true, or you misunderstood what you were taught.

Comment: @G.Smith Probably the latter; it's been a while since I had physics class in school. Is it not true that $KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$?

Comment: I was referring to $KE=\gamma mc^2$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to subtract the rest energy from the total energy to get the kinetic energy, so that kinetic energy is zero for a body at rest. In other words,
$$\text{KE} = (\gamma-1)mc^2.$$
You will find that this expression reduces to $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ at low velocities.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but thank you for the answer. I am however still a bit confused. For v<<c, doesn't the lorentz factor reduce to 1 (since $\frac{v^2}{c^2} \approx 0$), which would give a kinetic energy of 0? This just happened to me while I was trying to do some experimental calculations...

Comment: @Jonas That's the lowest order approximation you can make for $\gamma$. It doesn't capture how $\gamma$ varies with $v$ at all, and it's clearly not a good enough approximation in this case. Try the binomial expansion for small $v/c$, keeping only the first order term.

Comment: What I was confused about that when calculating the kinetic energy with both formulas for some small mass and non-relativistic velocity (e.g. 10kg and 50m/s), the non-relativistic formula gives $12500 \frac{kg*m^2}{s^2}$ and the relativistic formula gives 0.

Comment: Posted a [Follow-up question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592579/why-does-the-relativistic-kinetic-energy-formula-give-wrong-results-for-non-rela)

Answer (score 5):

(I originally intended to post this as an answer to your follow-up question, [Why does the relativistic kinetic energy formula give wrong results for non-relativistic velocities?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/592579/123208), but since that one is now closed, I'll post it here).

As already mentioned, in your kinetic energy calculation you forgot to subtract the rest mass-energy from the total energy. So you need $\gamma-1$ in that equation, not $\gamma$.

Let $E_N$ be the Newtonian kinetic energy, and $E_R$ be the relativistic kinetic energy. So

$$E_N=\frac12 mv^2$$
$$E_R=(\gamma-1)mc^2$$

When $v=0$, $\gamma=1$ and $E_N=E_R=0$, so the two equations clearly agree. For small $v>0$, we expect $E_N\approx E_R$, so

$$\frac12 mv^2 \approx (\gamma-1)mc^2$$
$$v^2/c^2 \approx 2(\gamma-1)$$
Let $\beta=v/c$. We want to show that for $v \ll c$,
$$q=\frac{\beta^2}{\gamma-1} \approx 2$$

Now
$$1/\gamma^2=1-\beta^2$$
So
$$\beta^2=\frac{\gamma^2-1}{\gamma^2}$$
Hence
$$q=\frac{\gamma^2-1}{\gamma^2(\gamma-1)}$$
$$q=\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma^2}$$

For small $\beta$, $\gamma\approx 1$, and so is $\gamma^2$, so
$$q\approx \frac{1+1}{1}=2$$

Here's a semi-logarithmic graph of $q$ vs $\beta$. As you can see, $q$ stays close to 2 until $\beta$ gets fairly large.
[image: Graph of beta^2/(gamma-1)]

---

As noted in your follow-up question, you can run into rounding errors when attempting to calculate $\gamma$, $\gamma-1$ or $q$, unless you're using arbitrary precision arithmetic. However, with a little bit of algebra it's possible to get good approximations for these quantities using standard arithmetic functions in a programming language, or a calculator that supports scientific notation. (You can even get reasonable results from a plain calculator without scientific notation, you just have to adjust the decimal places manually to keep the numbers in range). We *could* do this using methods from calculus, like Taylor series expansions, but there's a simpler way.

The core issue is how to get an accurate value of $\gamma-1$ when $\beta$ is small. The relationship between $1/\gamma$ and $\beta$ is Pythagorean, and we can use a simple Pythagorean formula to simplify things.

For all $k$,

$$(k^2+1)^2 = (k^2-1)^2 + (2k)^2$$
Let
$$\beta=\frac{2k}{k^2+1}$$
then
$$\gamma=\frac{k^2+1}{k^2-1}$$
and
$$\gamma-1=\frac{2}{k^2-1}$$
$$\gamma+1=\frac{2k^2}{k^2-1}$$

Substituting into
$$q=\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma^2}$$
we get
$$q=\left(\frac{2k^2}{k^2-1} \right) \left(\frac{k^2-1}{k^2 +1}\right)^2$$
$$q=\frac{2k^2(k^2-1)}{(k^2 +1)^2}$$

Let $z=(k^2+1)$

Thus
$$q=\frac{2(z-1)(z-2)}{z^2}$$
$$=\frac{2(z^2-3z+2)}{z^2}$$
$$q=2(1-3/z+2/z^2)$$
or
$$q=2 - 6/(k^2+1) + 4/(k^2+1)^2$$

So we now have expressions for $\gamma-1$ and $q-2$ that can be safely calculated. Given $k$, we don't even need to calculate any square roots! But how can we easily find $k$ given $\beta$? For small $\beta$, $k\approx 2/\beta$, and that's actually a very reasonable approximation for $\beta < 0.01$.

Let $n=2/\beta$, so
$$n=\frac{k^2+1}{k}$$
or
$$n=k+1/k$$
Note that we can use either $k$ or its reciprocal to represent $n$ (and hence $\beta, \gamma$, etc).

$$k^2+1=nk$$
which we can solve exactly:
$$k=\frac{n\pm\sqrt{n^2-4}}{2}$$ (Note that the two solutions are reciprocals, we want the larger solution).

That exact value is necessary for large $\beta$, but for such velocities we might as well use the standard formulae and not mess around with $k$. ;)

For smaller velocities, to get more accuracy than $k=n$ we can use $k=n-1/n$, and if we want more accuracy we can iterate $k \leftarrow n - 1/k$ a few times. It doesn't converge quickly, but it does alright even for $\beta\approx 0.1$. If you want to explore how quickly it converges for various $\beta$, see this [interactive Python / Sage script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzyMwrSS1KTC7hSklNU8hNzMzTSEotSbQ10DPUtOJSAII8WyN9kBCYk22bB6GzbTXytIsLi0o08uKMdE00NfWNwBIFRUADNbKzdRTUQ4pKU9U1waLlGZk5qQqJScUa2brZ2ZoKdgqGegauuoZGECuQNGrCBYBW6RrqZwMA_okptw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Here's a slightly [more detailed interactive script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVkMFqwzAMhu95CsEOsZsGxybdloFhLzAYYbcxRuq6wThx18QNNE8_xelY7dMvfdIvWQ9Q667xZjL-Cqrp1AWj0wD7K7y_gaiNaxMlRVU9VaLcPSevxnk9NMonB32EvjGOTHJXFMU2AXz2uz8dtBx1pxXakM_UpVtIHeTAWZAfw0WDTb8ofQkde-0bWddkYoqGhJOCLcnVz0risvE8eOI2Li8pZSIAc_ybJXHEahUapAtad1HFbX5Ul2PmVjvqe2JtCFqOmxC7sTlfN5slBhkP-mfAQ5B0WRQjiT9bJL1nbvVbmIvAeoIArI2I_W-JQdv0PQ6SwCFD2PKInm9tICBH-shmPPRSV7KZzfQXc3Z58Q==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)
, which calculates $\gamma-1$ and $q$ from $v$, with 3 options for $k$: $n$, $n-1/n$, or the true value. You can enter expressions like `0.1*c` and `c/50` into the `v` input box. (Those scripts are actually encoded into the URL itself, not stored on the SageMath server).

Answer (score 2):

You must expand the expression to the first 3 terms of the Taylor expansion, for $v$ small. $v=0$ is not small but zero, what means zero kinetic energy.

For small u: $f(u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \approx 1 + \frac{1}{2}u^2$

And also subtracting the rest energy as mentioned by Puk.