# What will happen to a relativistic giant ring encircling the Earth?

Tags: special-relativity

Imagine a giant ring encircling the Earth is spinning at relativistic speed, so that every point of the ring is accelerating at the same rate and at the same time. Will the ring breaks or the circumference shrinks instead? The ring is solid and continuous piece of metal.

Comment: This might be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox

Comment: No normal solid can spin at a relativistic speed. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/686011/123208