# Non-relativistic limit of relativistic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, calculus

I was reading a book and came across a formula which gives relativistic kinetic energy of a moving body with velocity $v=ßc$, where $c$ is speed of light. The formula is shown in image (equation number 1.12)

[image: Relativisttic Energy]

What I need to know is how for small values of ß, equation 1.12 becomes equation 1.13?

Comment: This book explains how old quantum theory was developed into new quantum mechanics and it explains how application of quantization in various fields of physics were done earlier. It is a part of equation.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/595175/123208

Comment: The site standard for displaying mathematics is [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Posting images of text or mathematics is very strongly discouraged.

Comment: A note, the letter in these equations is the Greek letter beta $\beta$ not the Germanic sharp s. Though this is neither here nor there.

Answer (score 3):

Taylor series to first order:

$$ \frac 1 {1-\epsilon} \approx 1 + \epsilon $$
$$ \sqrt{1 + \epsilon} \approx 1 + \frac 1 2 \epsilon $$

Comment: Thank you for giving answer