How to understand $W=pc$ in Feynman's Lectures on physics?
Pictures below are from 34-3 of Feynman's Lectures on physics.  I can't understand the red line.
The $p$ is momentum, $c$ is light speed. I can't understand the red line. I feel the author think $pc$ is the kinetic energy, since the total energy should be rest energy adding kinetic energy.
But if it is kinetic energy, it should be $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, which is not equal to $pc$, evenly $v\approx c$. So, what the $pc$ is ?







This is just an approximation . $$\sqrt {x+y} - \sqrt x$$  becomes smaller and smaller as $x$ becomes larger and larger compared to $y$. Thus practically $$\sqrt {x+y} ≈ \sqrt x$$ . In those cases also $p^2c^2>>m^2c^4$ so the approximation is quite acurate . Thus $W≈\sqrt {p^2c^2}=pc$

@Users  I know it is approximation. But why $pc$ is energy?   The kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ which is not like $pc$.

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ in not the kinetic energy in special relativity .

You may find my answer helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/595175/123208 especially the first part.

$pc$ is the total energy of a massless relativistic particle, like the photon. Electrons do have mass, so what's the catch?
Well, if the momentum of the electron is very big, then we can neglect the rest energy, so that $E=\sqrt{(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2}\approx pc$. A massive particle for which this approximation is valid is called an ultrarelativistic particle.
Finally, with respect to your confusion with kinetic energy, in SR, $KE = \sqrt{(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2} - mc^2$, which in the non-relativistic limit ($v/c \ll 1$) is the classical $m v^2/2$ (Taylor expand, while remembering that $p = \gamma mv$).

Thanks, could you detail talk about "the non-relativistic limit is the classical $p^2/2m$" ? It seemly be not obvious.

Yeah, you have to do a taylor expansion considering $v/c \ll 1$, and remembering that in SR $p = \gamma mv$. I added it to the text now.

Thanks. I forgot all about it. In fact, there is the process of calculability in 16-4 and 16-5.

$$W=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}$$ approaches $W=pc$ for $p\gg mc$ and $W=mc^2+{p^2\over 2m} = mc^2+{1\over 2}mv^2$ for $p\ll mc$.
